# why my nginx server cant reach index.html.but others page i can get no problem

Tags: nginx

could you give me a hand,
i had correct config my nginx server i think
but i cant reach index.html,the conf file configruation as below
only index.html has problem,others no problem

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name example.com;

        location = / {
                root /home/projects/temporary;
                index index.html;
        }


        location /test {
                alias /home/projects/temporary/test;
        }

        location /test2 {
                alias /home/projects/temporary;
        }


        location ~* .*\.(png|html|js|css|jpg)$ {
                root /home/projects/temporary/static;
        }
}
```

Comment: Your current configuration places `index.html` in the `/home/projects/temporary/static` folder. Is that the correct folder for the file?

Comment: what is your expected path for index.html